# Can't call "sh" inside a class on my Rakefile

Tags: ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm new to ruby, and I'm writing a pretty basic Rakefile. It contains a class `Installer` that has a method `shell` which calls `sh` like this:

```
class Installer
  def shell(command)
    sh command
  end
end
```

When I run it, it throws

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `sh' for #<Installer:0x00007ffde8098b78>`
```

I have done some research to see what's wrong but most similar errors appear to be framework/library related, whereas my problem seems to be that it's just not possible to call `sh` from inside a method.

Is this the problem? if so, what options do I have (considering I want the program to crash if the command failed (which I believe system or backticks won't help here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `sh` invocation to `Rake.sh`. At least, that seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `system` method from the `Kernel` module returns false if the command run from the shell returns a non-zero value.

```
irb(main):002:0> system('exit 1')
=> false

irb(main):003:0> system('exit 0')
=> true
```

You can you use this as a way to exit on non-zero returns from your shell commands.